# Prove of beaing Norm function

Tags: normed-spaces

Prove that relations beneath have conditions for being a norm function

A) for $C^{n}:  \left \| x \right \|= \left (\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left | \xi _{j} \right |^{2}  \right )^{1/2}$

B) for $C\left[a,b\right]: \left \| x \right \|=\displaystyle{\max_{t\in [a,b]}} \:\left | x(t) \right |$

Comment: should the first one not be on a space of sequences rather than functions?

Comment: I think he means that $||.|| : x \mapsto ||x||$ is a norm function. Anyway, what have you tried so far ? You just have to mechanically check the axioms, the only point that can be hard is the triangular inequality for the first one, you should use Minkowski inequality

Comment: @YannHamdaoui
Yes that makes sense, but say $x$ was a function on $[0,1]$ we can't have a sequence running over these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(B) we need to show:

(i) $\|x\|\ge 0,\forall x\in C[a,b]$ and $\|x\|=0\iff x=0$

(ii)$\|\alpha x\|=|\alpha|\|x\|,\forall\alpha\in\Bbb R,\forall x\in C[a,b]$

(iii) $\|x+y\|\le\|x\|+\|y\|,\forall x,y\in C[a,b]$

Proof:

(i)$\|x\|=\max_{t\in[a,b]}|x(t)|\ge 0$ since $|\cdot|$ is a norm.

$\|x\|=0\Rightarrow \max_{t\in[a,b]}|x(t)|=0\Rightarrow |x(t)|\le 0\Rightarrow x=0$

$x=0\Rightarrow \|x\|=\|0\|= \max_{t\in[a,b]}|0|=0$.

(ii)$\|\alpha x\|=\max_{t\in[a,b]}|\alpha x(t)|=|\alpha|\max_{t\in[a,b]}|x(t)|=|\alpha|\|x\|$

(iii)|x+y|\le|x|+|y|\le \max_{t\in[a,b]}|x(t)|+\max_{t\in[a,b]}|y(t)|=\|x\|+\|y\|$

$\Rightarrow \max_{t\in[a,b]}|x(t)+y(t)|\le \max_{t\in[a,b]}|x(t)|+\max_{t\in[a,b]}|y(t)|$

$\Rightarrow \|x+y\|\le\|x\|+\|y\|$